# GridColumn labelFunction not bindable

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

Recently i noticed one problem when using labelFunction for gridColumn:
It does not refresh, when nested (displayed) property is changed.

```
// SomeClass and SomeSubClass has [Bindable] metadata
[Bindable]
private var someSubClass:SomeSubClass;
[Bindable]
private var someClass:SomeClass;

private function inits():void{
    someSubClass = new SomeSubClass();
    someSubClass.value = "SomeSubValue";
    someClass = new SomeClass();
    someClass.subclass = someSubClass;
    var ac:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
    ac.addItem(someClass);
    dg.dataProvider = ac;    
}
private function myLabelFunction(item:Object, column:GridColumn):String
{
    return (item.subclass)? item.subclass.value : "";
}
```

mxml

```
<s:Button click="someSubClass.value = 'Hello World'"/>
<s:DataGrid dataProvider="{dataProvider}" width="100%" height="200">
    <s:columns>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <s:GridColumn labelFunction="{myLabelFunction}" headerText="NoRenderer"/>
            <s:GridColumn headerText="WithRenderer">
                <s:itemRenderer>
                    <fx:Component>
                          <s:GridItemRenderer>
                              <s:Label text="{data.subclass.value}"/>
                          </s:GridItemRenderer>
                    </fx:Component>
                </s:itemRenderer>
            </s:gridColumn>
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:columns>
</s:DataGrid>
```

When button clicked first column which use labelFunction still displaing old value, but second column (with custom renderer) works fine. I am trying to use as less as possible custom item renderers for performance issue. Or something wrong with my label function?

Comment: A bit of a shot in the dark but have you tried marking myLabelFunction as [Bindable]?  So long as elements are modified using the ArrayCollection and not it's underlying source then I believe it will trigger refresh events, if you just modify the object without updating the array collection it won't automatically dispatch a collection refresh event.

Comment: Yes i did. I was trying [Bindable] and [Bindable(event="propertyChange")] - no luck

Comment: there is a way to dispatch update event to parent class:
_dg.dataProvider.itemUpdated(dg.dataProvider.getItemAt(0))_
but in my application those classes are part of different models, and subclass doesnt know nothing about parent class, meaning subclass may be a child of many other classes

Comment: Though it may not be ideal you should be able to trigger the grid to refresh after you make the change to the data by calling dg.invalidateList() http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74269/what-is-the-difference-between-invalidatelist-and-invalidatedisplaylist but this assumes you have some other way of knowing the list data has been modified and can get a handle on the grid from there (could use a singleton but it's a bit messy)

Comment: Good idea. Model itemUpdate function dispatch "refreshEvent", which is managed by parsley, then in view  i use [MessageHandler] function to listen for all "refreshEvent"s and if type is match do invalidateList(). thank You

Comment: @shaunhusain Methods can't be marked bindable unless they are get set methods.  Bindable on the labelFunction won't have any affect, although I may expect a compiler warning.  Additionally, the labelFunction is not changing.  If I had to guess--for performance reasons--the renderers are not redrawn.  I bet if you scroll you'll see the updated values, though.  Try calling the refresh() or itemUpdated() methods on the dataProvider.  It seems you are alkready playing w/ that idea.  I don't understand why that wouldn't work.

Comment: @Reboog711 you're right, thanks for the correction, my brain has been in JavaScript/AngularJS mode lately so my AS3/Flex is starting to slip a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never tried this, but I'm not surprised that it won't update.  In the second example, you've explicitly set a binding chain on data.subclass.value.  In the first case with myLabelFunction, there's no binding set up on item.subclass, so Flex won't have any "magic" way of knowing you'd like to watch that value for changes.

I would go with the custom renderer, I'm not sure what your particular performance concerns are but it should be manageable as long as you leave virtual layout / renderer recyling on.

Comment: Yes You are right. Considering everything, i thing that using custom ItemRenderer is a less expensive way.